# Shower rooms at Incheon airport

Tags: transit, south-korea, hygiene, icn

I will be in transit at the Incheon airport for a couple hours and wanted to make use of their 'shower rooms'. Has anybody used them? Can you take your luggage in the shower room?

The airport's website links you to http://www.wellss.com/new/wellss_service_shower.htm and they have some pictures of the showers here - http://www.wellss.com/new/hub_shower/

At least from the pictures it seems one can easily take their carry on luggage with them inside the shower room. Just wanted to confirm with someone that it was indeed the case. I don't wish to leave my carry-on luggage else where.

Alternatively, are there any good wet wipes for freshening up for long flights?

Comment: I do not have experience of that facility, although I have used the Korean Air lounge in Incheon and you can certainly take your carry on baggage in. This is true of all other airports I have visited as well.

Answer (score 11):

I completed my travel. I can confirm that the shower rooms are completely self contained. You can leave your luggage at the front desk or carry it with you inside. The shower rooms look exactly like the pictures. The towels are small in size and you need to ask for multiple ones for an adult. It doesn't cost anything even for the "amenities". The only thing I'd like to report here is that the shower rooms do not seem to be cleaned after each use so you better be lucky whoever used it before you left it in a good condition.

Comment: Hm, it's free? Are there long queues?

Comment: No long queues for the showers

Comment: @Null If you think your self-answer gets your question resolved, please accept it.

Answer (score 5):

I've been. The queues aren't very long. When I went I only had to wait for 1 person. It just depends on who is there before you really. I would suggest not to take too long because after a while you will get a knock on your door.

Towels are very small - more like hand towels but I couldnt really complain seeing as the toilet and shower are free with free toiletries too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can take the luggage inside. You can entrust it at the front desk, but I don't recommend it.

The price is entirely free, but if you want to get a massage the next to the shower room, you must pay for it (I don't know about the price and the staff at the counter didn't know, either.).

You can use the room up to 30 minutes; In my experience, there wasn't any queues there.

The room is consisted of the shower and toilet, and towels and bath soaps. If the stock of towels runs out, you can ask the staff at the counter and receive it.