# Where to shower for free in Singapore airport?

Tags: transit, hygiene, singapore, singapore-airlines

I have a similar question to this [Shower rooms at Incheon airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18532/4584) 
My buddy has an 8 hour layover in Singapore. Is there any place where one could shower for free at Changi (Singapore) airport? 
[The one location mentioned on their site](http://www.changiairport.com/shopping-and-dining/faq#fac03) charges $9 for a shower!

Comment: I saw a person do a sponge bath in a toilet before!!

Answer (score 15):

Many years ago there used to be free showers at Changi, but they have since been removed.

Today the options are :

- The Ambassador Transit Hotels as you've listed in terminals 1, 2 and 3 (SGD $8.56, including a free non-alcoholic drink)
- The Ambassador Transit Lounge in terminals 2 and 3 (same price as above)
- The Rooftop Pool at the Ambassador Transit Hotel in terminal 1 (SGD $13.91 for pool/showers/free non-alcoholic drink)
- The Rainforest Lounge in terminal 1 (Around $10, more if you want to use the rest of the lounge)

All options will provide towels and toiletries.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe so. [SleepInAirport](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/singapore.htm#.UnZ9J_mnqQA) lists 5 places you can shower, and all are pay lounges / areas.

That said, Changi was also the [top-rated airport](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/2015/best-airports-world.htm) for RnR during a stopover, so maybe a nap is enough to freshen up...?

Comment: Btw where did you get "Changi is top-rated airport for RnR" from? Rated by?

Comment: Now updated - it was the SleepingInAirports 2015 traveller survey, Changi ranked top.