# Arriving in Singapore at 1AM, where to wait until things open in the morning?

Tags: singapore, airport-terminals

I plan to arrive (from Taipei) at Changi airport at about 1:00 AM local time on a weekday. Airports often have little or no place to "hang out" or snooze after arrival.

Instead of paying USD 50 or more for a hotel in the city, is there something I can do to sit and close my eyes for a few hours until businesses and other spots open in the morning? It could be in the airport, or the city, I'm assuming at least some buses run all night.

I'll just have a backpack, no need to store luggage.

From [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21599/59997) I've found sleepinginairports.net [1](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/singapore.htm), [2](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/2015/best-airports-sleeping.htm), [3](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/2015/best-airports-world.htm) but I have a hunch that's for transit, and I'm not sure if that's an option.

Comment: Not sure if that’s the case in all terminals, but at least in terminals 1, 2 and 3, you arrive in the transit/departures area, so anything that’s available for departing or transit passengers is available to you as well.

Comment: If everything goes in time, it may be worthy sleeping if you have got something booked previously. Honesty for me by the time I find something and unwind would be already 5PM, so I would thought about heading for a room of for the nearest macdonalds. Get some sleep on-flight just in case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Changi does not separate arrivals and departures, so **you can use any facilities anywhere in the airport** simply by not going through immigration.  However, if you have checked bags, it may take some time to retrieve them the next morning.

That said, I would still recommend you head over to the city.  Changi is a nice place to transit but you're not going to get a good night's sleep without paying for the transit hotel, and regular non-airport hotels are much cheaper.

Comment: This is just what I needed to know, thank you for the speedy reply! I'll spend some more time checking for more places in the city as well.